# Filling of LOX tanks - 'cryogenic geyser cycling'

Tags: terminology, lox, fuel-system

[This](http://spacenews.com/spacexs-musk-says-sabotage-unlikely-cause-of-sept-1-explosion-but-still-a-worry/) article about the 2016 Sept 1 Falcon 9 explosion mention 'cryogenic geyser cycling' in reference to the filling of the LOX tanks as though it were a particular method of filling tanks.

> In cryogenic geyser cycling environments, such as SpaceX’s rapid filling of a LOX tank at 66 Kelvin, you have violent variations of temperature between the interior and exterior.

What is 'cryogenic geyser cycling'?

Comment: 'Geysering' in booster Lox feedlines is a phenomenon that happens before ignition when relatively warm propellant starts to rise in the feedline. Shuttle prevented this by bubbling helium through the feedline to keep the lox mixed and prevent stratification. I am unable to reconcile this with the use of the term in the linked article.

Comment: Re-read the linked article more closely.  It sounds to me that the article has been translated into English or written by someone who does not have English as a first language.  I am betting that 'cryogenic geyser cycling environments' is not what was meant originally.

Comment: @OrganicMarble so this might be an issue related to 'water goats' or 'hydraulic rams'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [cryogenic geyser](https://books.google.nl/books?id=K3gtSIuOkXgC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=cryogenic%20geyser&source=bl&ots=NTvEjpOFzM&sig=bHJh0tqDPAZtFr8FPg7xakkDx7Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE8PDg7-PPAhVLthoKHTA4BsoQ6AEIITAA#v=onepage&q=cryogenic%20geyser&f=false) occurs when a volume of cryogenic liquid inside e.g. a pipe suddenly boils, propelling the liquid/gas mixture through the pipe and into its destination at high speed.

The pipe can then refill (potentially causing a water hammer), and the process may repeat. If it does, you have cryogenic geyser cycling.

So it's not so much a filling process as a phenomenon you want to avoid.