# Anti-Geyser Test Full Scale

Tags: launch-vehicle, testing, lox

I am working on the thesis about Geysering and Recirculation in Launch Vehicles. And I am having some diffucilties to understand that "do we need to use full-scale model to test geysering?". As in https://www.nasa.gov/sls/anti-geyser-testing.html . Are there any other possible ways to determine whether geyser occurs or not, or recirculation is enough to mitigate that issue. I have seen something called "Murphy Curve" (Fig.1. ref-> AN EXPERIMENTAL INVESTIGATION OF
GEYSERING IN VERTICAL TUBES - D.W. Murphy 1965), but in some recent papers it is said that this Murphy Curve is not valid for all cases.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Fig.1. Murphy Curve]

Comment: slightly related: [What is "anti-geysering" and why would you turn it off 70 seconds before launch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55823/12102) and perhaps [Filling of LOX tanks - 'cryogenic geyser cycling'](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18677/12102)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1725/

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys, I'm not seeing an issue here.  The line isn't the collective slope of all the data, it's the approximate dividing line between the "black" and "white" regions of the graph.